# Why does the built-in Download Booster on Samsung not work with UC browser?

Tags: samsung, downloading

Download Booster is a built-in function on Samsung devices, and it works great when downloading a file more than 30MB from the Play Store. However, it does not work when downloading a file via the UC browser.

Why?

Answer (score 4):

### It does not work / has limited support with Third-Party applications.

Have a look at the following article by Samsung on their homepage:
[What is the Download Booster and how do I enable it on my Samsung Galaxy Alpha?](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/skp/faq/1061358)

It seems like that the download booster is only available when downloading via the integrated Browser / Samsung Apps / Google Apps. 
See this image for the download browser description:
[image: Download-Booster description]
<sup>Thanks [Samsung for providing this picture](http://skp.samsungcsportal.com/upload/namo/FAQ/uk/20140402/images/000001/GS5_-_Enable_Download_Booster.png)</sup>

The last sentence pretty much says that **third-party applications might not work** with the download booster.

You can also have a look at [Even though Download booster feature on Galaxy S5 is enable, it does not work to download contents. What is the problem?](http://www.samsung.com/ae/support/skp/faq/1042649).

I'm quoting the essential part:

> 2. This feature supports Hypertext Transmission Protocol (HTTP) 1.1 only.
>      So, It can be activated in Play Store, Samsung Apps, Samsung Video , YouTube, Play Movies, Play Games,   Internet(S-Browser), Chrome (ChromeBrowser), Baidu, and not all applications.
>      The feature cannot be used with other protocols, such as HTTPS or FTP.
>      So, it’s not supported regarding to attached files of E-mail , Streaming service like  Dropbox or Twitter

Comment: Good find, benjamin. Especially focus on the last sentence in the second screenshot explicitly: ***This does not apply to applications downloaded from Samsung Apps and Play Store.***